# Why does this simple use of the State monad cause a stack overflow?

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, monads, state-monad

I was playing around with the State monad, and I don't know what's causing the stack overflow in this simple piece of code.

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

tick :: State Int Int
tick = do n <- get
         put $! (n+1)
         return n

million :: Int
million = snd $ runState (mapM_ (const tick) [1..1000000]) 0

main = print million
```

**Note**
I would just like to know what's causing the problem in this piece of code, the task itself is not important per se.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question: you might like `replicateM`.

Comment: I see `import Control.Monad.State.Lazy` and `put $! (n+1)` and I am immediately suspicious...

Comment: @DanBurton It was actually `Control.Monad.State` at the beginning and then I found it the same as `C.M.S.Lazy` so I changed it. I forgot all about `C.M.S.Strict` though :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that Control.Monad.State.Lazy's (>>=) is so lazy that even the ($!) doesn't help you.
Try Control.Monad.State.Strict, that should reach the ($!).

The (>>=) of the lazy state monad doesn't look at all at the (value,state) pair, so the only way to get some evaluation done before the end is reached is having the `f` in `m >>= f` deconstruct the pair. That doesn't happen here, so you get a huge thunk, that is too large for the stack when runState finally wants a result.

Okay, I've eaten, now I can elaborate. Let me use the old (mtl-1.x) definition of the lazy `State s` monad, it's a bit easier to see there without the inner monad. The new (mtl-2.x) definition `type State s = StateT s Identity` behaves the same, it's just more writing and reading. The definition of (>>=) was

```
m >>= k  = State $ \s -> let
    (a, s') = runState m s
    in runState (k a) s'
```

Now, `let` bindings are lazy, hence this is

```
m >>= k = State $ \s -> let
    blob = runState m s
    in runState (k $ fst blob) (snd blob)
```

only more readable. So the (>>=) lets the blob completely unevaluated. Evaluation is only required if `k` needs to inspect `fst blob` to determine how to continue, or `k a` needs to inspect `snd blob`.

In `replicateM r tick`, the computations are chained with (>>), so the `k` in (>>=)'s definition is `const tick`. As a constant function, it most definitely doesn't need to inspect its argument. So `tick >> tick` becomes

```
State $ \s -> 
    let blob1 = (\n -> let n' = n+1 in seq n' ((),n')) s
        blob2 = (\m -> let m' = m+1 in seq m' ((),m')) (snd blob1)
    in blob2
```

the `seq` isn't touched until `blobN` has to be evaluated. But needing to evaluate it to the outermost constructor - the pair constructor `(,)` - would be enough to trigger the seq and that would in turn lead to complete evaluation here. Now, in `million`, nothing requires any evaluation until the final `snd` after the `runState` is reached. By that time, a thunk with a million layers has been built. Evaluating that thunk requires pushing many `let m' = m+1 in seq m' ((),m')` on the stack until the initial state is reached, and if the stack is large enough to hold them, they'd then be popped and applied. So it'd be three traversals, 1. building the thunk, 2. peeling layers from the thunk and pushing them on the stack, 3. consuming the stack.

The (>>=) of Control.Monad.State.Strict is just strict enough to force the `seq` s on each bind, thus there's only one traversal, no (nontrivial) thunk is built and the computation runs in constant space.
The definition is

```
m >>= k = State $ \s ->
    case runState m s of
      (a, s') -> runState (k a) s'
```

The important difference is that pattern matching in `case` expressions is strict, here the `blob` has to be evaluated to the outermost constructor to match it against the pattern in the `case`.
With `m = tick = State (\m -> let m' = m+1 in seq m' ((),m'))` the essential part becomes

```
case let s' = s+1 in seq s' ((),s') of
    (a, s'') -> runState (k a) s''
```

The pattern-match demands the evaluation of `((), s')` [to the (,) constructor], by the `seq` that is tied to the evaluation of `s' = s+1`, everything is fully evaluated on each bind, no thunks, no stack.

However, you still need to be careful. In this case, due to the `seq` (resp. `($!)`) and the shallow structure of the involved types,evaluation kept up with application of `(>>)`. In general, with deeper structured types and/or without `seq`s, C.M.S.Strict also builds large thunks which can lead to stack overflow. The thunks are just a bit simpler and less entangled than those generated by C.M.S.Lazy in those circumstances.

On the other hand, the laziness of C.M.S.Lazy allows other computations that are impossible with C.M.S.Strict. For example, C.M.S.Lazy provides one of the very few monads where

```
take 100 <$> mapM_ something [1 .. ]
```

terminates. [But be aware that the state is then unusable; before it could be used, it would have to travel through the entire infinite list. So, if you do something like that, before you can resume state-dependent computations, you have to `put` a fresh state.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. I also noticed in the sources `C.M.S.Lazy` uses lazy patterns while `C.M.S.Strict` does not and that's what's causing the difference in the current version. Your explanation with the old version is clearer though, thanks again.

Comment: In your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8763702/722938), you had to explicitly use lazy pattern matching, but in your above explanation you mentioned that let bindings are lazy. Could you please elaborate on difference between the two cases?

Comment: In that answer, the lazy pattern is a function argument. The function argument in a function definition - regardless of whether the function is bound in a let or not - causes a pattern-match when the function is called. Pattern-matching is strict, unless the pattern is irrefutable (a variable, a wildcard, or a lazy pattern `~pattern`). Since there the function then becomes the argument of `fix`, it must not be strict, so its argument must be an irrefutable pattern. Instead of `~(st:sts)`, one could use a variable and deconstruct it with `head` and `tail`, but `~(st:sts)` is nicer.