# Infinite list of infinite counters

Tags: haskell, infinite

For those with suspicious minds, this is not homework, just curious.

Given a finite alphabet, is it possible to construct a list of infinitely long words made from the alphabet in reverse lexographic order?

i.e. given the alphabet `"ab"`

is it possible to construct the list:

```
["aaaaaa...", "baaaaa...", "abaaaa...", "bbaaaa...", "aabaaa...", ...]
```

where `...` represents the list (and list of lists) extending to infinite length.

A naïve attempt is:

```
counters alphabet = [c:ounter | ounter <- counters alphabet, c <- alphabet]
```

but this doesn't work since it is left recursive.

Of course, with a working version, if you tried to print the result, you would only see the first element being printed as an infinite list of the first element from the alphabet.  However,  you should be able to do this:

```
mapM_ (print . take 2) . take 4 . counters $ "ab"
```

and see the output:

```
aa
ba
ab
bb
```

Comment: you are aware there are uncountably many words, so the list won't include all of them?

Comment: isn't there an isomorphism to the set of positive integers?  The a's to the right of the last b are like leading zeros in an integer

Comment: Yes, but you wrote in the question "all infinitely long words"; it's not all, only those which are composed of "a" from some point.

Comment: Yeah, seems like if you are looking at all infinite length strings, you have a pretty easy isomorphism to the set of real numbers in [0, 1). Right? Reverse lexicographic order in that sense would be interpreted as the usual ordering relation between reals.

Comment: Patrick87: if you mean binary expansion, it's not isomorphism: 0.0111111... = 0.10000...

Comment: Removed "all".  I guess "reverse lexographic order" is a bit ambiguous, since it is the words that are reversed, not the result.

Comment: If you're happy with only the strings that trail off into `aaa...`, then why not just generate all finite words and tack on `aaa...`?

Comment: there is no finite point at which they all trail off to `aaa...`

Comment: In the answers you accepted, every one of the infinite words eventually trails off into `aaa...`.

Comment: In fact, doing so seems to be a requirement of your "reverse lexicographic order". The first thing that doesn't trail off into `aaa...` would have to come after all of the things that do, of which there are infinitely many.

Comment: @redxaxder I tried it. There are an annoying number of special cases, because all the finite words in the sequence `"", "a", "aa", "aaa", ...` produce the same infinite word. I didn't find a solution that was reasonably elegant (few special cases) and reasonably efficient (e.g. no use of `nub`) at the same time.

Comment: If the last letter comes from `tail alphabet` then there won't be any collisions when you tack on the `aaa...`. You also won't miss anything.

Comment: @redxaxder, sorry for being so slow.  I was confusing finite length with fixed length.  Yes, I see what you're saying now.  Thanks.

Comment: @redxaxder You will miss something: `aaaaaaa...`. Maybe you're starting to see what I mean about special cases? =)

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah. I guess it might be unusual to include the empty word in a list of finite words. On a slight tangent... what if you require that the list includes every periodic word? There are countably many, so cardinality won't get in the way.

Comment: @redxaxder If you want the list elements to be unique, there's still some subtle gotchas. Try it for yourself!

Comment: wouldn't reverse lexicographic order start with z?

Comment: @PyRulez the example alphabet consists only of the letters `a` and `b`.

Comment: Then wouldn't b be first in reverse alphabetical order?

Comment: @PyRulez good point.  "reverse lexicographic order" is ambiguous.  In this case, it refers to normal lexicographic order, but with the order of the letters within each individual work reversed, rather than the reversal of the order of the words themselves (see comment above from Jan 6 '12 at 20:42).

Comment: You can't reverse an infinite sequence bro. I think what is meant is that the first characters are the least significant in the comparison.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not `fix` it?

```
ghci> let bar = let foo ~(st:sts) = [c:st | c <- "ab"] ++ foo sts in fix foo
ghci> take 5 . map (take 5) $ bar
["aaaaa","baaaa","abaaa","bbaaa","aabaa"]
take 10 . map (take 5) $ bar
["aaaaa","baaaa","abaaa","bbaaa","aabaa","babaa","abbaa","bbbaa","aaaba","baaba"]
```

Comment: Sweet!  I was coming to the realization that a lazy pattern was required since it was not otherwise decidable whether the result was non-empty.

Answer (score 7):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but at least it works:

```
counters alphabet = map f [0..]
  where f n = let (q, r) = quotRem n (length alphabet) in alphabet !! r : f q
```

```
> take 10 $ map (take 5) $ counters "ab"
["aaaaa","baaaa","abaaa","bbaaa","aabaa","babaa","abbaa","bbbaa","aaaba","baaba"]
```

Answer (score 6):

You may find the following approach amusing/confusing:

```
duplicates s ss = cycle ss : duplicates s (ss >>= \c -> s >> [c])
counters = transpose . join duplicates
```

This comes from the observation that the first letters follow the pattern `"ababab..."`, the second letters follow the pattern `"aabbaabbaabb..."`, the third letters follow the pattern `"aaaabbbbaaaabbbb..."`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
f@(a:as) = a:('b':a):concatMap (\x -> ['a':x,'b':x]) as where a = ['a','a'..]
```

Also `(\x -> ['a':x,'b':x])` can be written in `Applicative` as `([('a':),('b':)] <*>) . pure` if you consider it to be more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The progression looks like encoding a base-N number with the least-significant-digit on the left, so we could approach it as

1. Make a "to base N" function `f` using your *alphabets* as the letters.
2. `map` `f` to `[0..]`
3. Append `repeat $ head alphabets` to each element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another version based on Daniel's idea:

```
counters = transpose $ map cycle $ iterate (>>= \x -> [x,x]) "ab"
```

Comment: Love the simplicity! Great way to generate words from any alphabet! For anyone that wonders, `(>>= \x -> [x,x])` equals `concat . map (\x -> [x,x])` for lists. Hence the complexity is optimal as well.